# Switched from natbib to biblatex, cannot find bib file

Tags: biblatex, natbib, texmaker

I had a working file with a natbib setup, but I encoutered difficulties citing in a footnote and it seemed more broadly that biblatex was better for my field. So I switched, and now my .tex file just can't seem to find my .bib file. I have also floated back and forth between certain Biber and Bibtex settings. After four hours of googling I am waving my white flag and crawling desperately for your help.

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibston.bib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

As for my errors, it tells me that all of my citations are undefined, and at the end it says:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex) "International RBC"
(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to '"International RBC".run.xml'.
\openout1 = `"International RBC.run.xml"'
```

Thank you so much for your help.

George

Comment: Check in the blg-file if you did run biber and if there were errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal, but complete example showing the problem? Just in case: did you follow the full cycle of compilations?

Comment: Ulrike Fischer: I do not see a blg file with the rest of them.

Bernard: In TexMaker, I do PDFLatex, Biblatex, and then a last one/two PDFLatex's. Is this correct?

Comment: To follow up on this: if I use natbib (changing my preamble and putting \bibliography{bib}{}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} at the end), everything works fine. But as soon as I change it to Bibtex, even if i delete my .aux files, everything becomes undefined. I dont know if I have ever been so frustrated.

Comment: There are 2 ways of building bibliographies. However from your question and comments I am not sure which ones you are trying to use. With biblatex, I think the default is `biber` (although you can use bibex if you specify it. with `natbib`, you have to use `bibtex`. So in your case, the workflow to compile your document should be `pdflatex` > `biber` >`pdflatex` > `pdflatex`. biber if the program that will compile your bibliography. Is this what you are doing?

Comment: @ArTourter firstly, thanks for your reply! Really appreciated. I was using natbib until I hit a problem citing in a footnote, and my readings suggested that biblatex was more versatile for my field (economics). So I tried out some suggestions. In fact, in my TexMaker, even if I do Options>Configure TexMaker and change the field to biber, I do not even see a compiler option for biber. That problem explains a lot! What you mentioned is my usual compilation combination, except with bibtex. How do I get a biber compiler? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Please have a look at [What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864) for advice on a switch from `natbib` to `biblatex`, [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for general information on running BibTeX and Biber. Finally, read [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) on how to make your editor run Biber.

Comment: If nothing seems to work, try compiling your document from the command line. That is navigate to the correct folder in the terminal/command line and issue the commands `pdflatex test`, `biber test`, `pdflatex test`, `pdflatex test` in that order, assuming your file is called `test.tex`. If you get any warnings or errors make note of those from the last pdfLaTeX run and the Biber run. You should also refer to the `.blg` and `.log` files after all those runs.

Comment: Any news here? I'm quite tempted to vote to close as a duplicate of [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864), the standard answer for problems that involve not being able to run Biber because of configuration issues in the edtior.

Comment: Embarassing as it is, I think it was due to a poor compilation cycle. Works fine now with biblatex. Sorry I couldnt be more helpful.